# C++11 modify values in std::discrete_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, probability

Is it possible to modify single value in std::discrete_distribution? I can't find a simple way of doing this. I was thinking of initializing it with std::vector with assigned probabilities and modifying it everytime I want, but reinitializing discrete_distribution everytime seems to be not the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, there's no following function in [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution).
You can get probabilities, but not set, so, there is only one way - reinit `discrete_distribuion` (probably you can use vector of predefined destributions).